# InsertSort em lista Duplamente Encadeada... sem sucesso

Tags: c

Estou tentando implementar o metodo InsertSort mas até agora sem sucesso.. 
alguem poderia me dar aquela força?

```
void insertionSort(ListDN *l){
int ordered = 0,i,j;

Dnode *cursor = l->head->next   ;
Dnode *aux;
Dnode *temp;
while(!ordered){
        ordered= 1;

        printf("%d cursor  \n", cursor->info);
        printf("%d  cursor->prev \n", cursor->prev->info);
        temp = cursor;
        while(cursor->prev != NULL && cursor->info < cursor->prev->info){ 

                troca(l, cursor->prev, cursor);



        }

        ordered= 0;
        cursor=temp->next;
        toList(l);  
    }
}
```

metodo troca...

```
void troca(ListDN *list, Dnode *n1, Dnode *n2 ){

Dnode *n1a = n1->prev;
Dnode *n1p = n1->next;
Dnode *n2a = n2->prev;
Dnode *n2p = n2->next;

if(n1->next == n2){
    n1p = n2;
    n2a = n1;

    if(n1a != NULL){
        n1a->next = n2;
    }else{
        list->head = n2;
      }

    n2->prev = n1a;
    n1->prev = n2;
    n2->next = n1;
    n1->next = n2p;

    if(n2p != NULL){
        n2p->prev = n1;
    }else{
        list->tail = n1;
    }

}else{

    if(n1a !=NULL){
        n1a->next = n2;
    }else{
        list->head = n2;
    }
    n2->prev = n1a;
    n1->prev = n2a;
    if(n2p != NULL){
        n2p->prev = n1;
    }else{
        list->tail = n1;
    }
    if(n1p != NULL){
        n1p->prev = n2;
    }
    if(n2a != NULL){
        n2a->next = n1;
    }
    n1->next = n2p;
    n2->next = n1p;
}
```

}

se alguem puder da uma ajuda por favor...

Comment: Como estão definidos `Dnode` e `ListDN`?

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct ListDN_ {
    int size;
    Dnode *head;
    Dnode *tail;
} ListDN;


typedef struct Double_node_ {
    int info;       
    struct Double_node_ *prev;
    struct Double_node_ *next;
} Dnode;
```